# getting redirected when searching from another view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

ok, so i have a project (Asp net core) that i am working on and i have created the controller and the model and i have implemented a searching mechanism here

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            var drugs = from m in _context.Drugs
                select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                drugs = drugs.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }



            return View(await drugs.ToListAsync());
        }
```

and it works very well so the issue is i can't search from my home page whenever i add the search string  and hit the button it redirects me to the drugs index i don't want that i have implemented a bootstrap modal and i want my results to be displayed there.so how can i search my model from another view without getting redirected please i need your help. Thanks a million

Comment: If you want to retreive data from your controller, you need to call your controller from javascript in your page with something like ajax or jQuery. You then return the raw data as json and handle updating your view client-side in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are just using a standard HTML form to submit the "search". It's not "redirecting" you; you are literally telling the browser to request a new URL and display that in the browser tab/window. If you want to remain on the same page, then you must use AJAX to make the request.

Comment: would you be kind enough to tell me/ show me or send me a link on how i can do that? thank you again

Comment: Google is your friend. Your question is too broad. You need to do your own research and attempt a solution on your own. If you run into issues, you can return here to ask specific questions about those.